# Can I ask this in Puzzling? In search for a specific riddle/answer

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a riddle/puzzle my friend confused a group of us yesterday. No one can figure it out. It seems logically impossible to solve so I want to search the original question but cannot find it. So I don't know if I can post the riddle here without knowing the answer nor knowing if the wording is correct.

The riddle doesn't make sense because we can't see how the dwarfs can possibly reach the other side since they can't cross paths nor can they be on the same side. If they somehow use the bucket and rocks to communicate, how would the other dwarf know what the "communication" attempt even means. I am starting to think this puzzle is worded wrong or is impossible and was constructed just to confuse my friend.

So, can I post this in Puzzling?

The riddle/puzzle :

> There are two dwarfs on opposite ends of the same mountain. Between
>   them there is a single track which is the only form of transportation
>   to reach the other side. Since it is a single track, if two carts
>   attempted to cross, they will collide. The dwarfs are not fond of each
>   other and connect meet. They have an unlimited amount of buckets and
>   rocks to communicate. Both dwarfs must reach the other side of the
>   mountain. They cannot be on the same side of the mountain at the same
>   time.

Hint: Supposedly this question originated from Steven's Institute of Technology which was told to my friend by his boss who was a graduate. The only hint he received is that this question supposedly has to do with how a computer processor works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is definitely within the scope of PSE. Just be clear, when you ask (as you have here), that it is not your puzzle and that you don't know what the solution is. You can use the tag, [puzzle-identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification) (plus maybe [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) and [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction), unless you have reason to believe [lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) is intended).

Comment: Thank you for response. I thought it would be acceptable but wanted to make sure in the meta.